# Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.9.1, but has dynamically loaded 2.8.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, nokogiri, libxml2

I want to run

```
bundle exec rake fixtures:populate_from_db
```

on CentOS but I get the following warning messages:

```
WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.9.1, but has dynamically loaded 2.8.0
rake aborted!
```

`~/.bundle/config` file contains:

```
BUNDLE_BUILD__NOKOGIRI: "--with-xml2-include=/opt/local/include/libxml2 --with-xml2-lib=/opt/local/lib --with-xslt-dir=/opt/local"
```

How should I compile Nokogiri again 2.8.0 version of LibXML?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you read through the various similar questions in the "Related" links on the lower right of this page? What happened when you tried those things?

Answer (score 7):

Try running:

`gem update --system` & `gem pristine nokogiri`

Just worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

The following steps solve my problem

```
gem uninstall nokogiri # remove nokogiri
NOKOGIRI_USE_SYSTEM_LIBRARIES=1 bundle install
```

Combine the solutions from 
https://simonharrer.wordpress.com/2013/05/01/fixing-nokogiri-warning-after-ubuntu-upgrade/
and
https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/wiki/What-to-do-if-libxml2-is-being-a-jerk

Comment: I needed to `sudo apt-get install libxslt1-dev` before
`NOKOGIRI_USE_SYSTEM_LIBRARIES=1 bundle install`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
gem install nokogiri -- --with-xml2-include=/usr/include/libxml2/libxml --with-xml2-lib=/usr/lib64/ --with-sxlt-include=/usr/include/libxslt --with-xslt-lib=/usr/lib64/
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it sounds silly, but try putting Nokogiri at the top of your Gemfile. This works in some cases where other gems conflict on native extensions

Answer (score 0):

I had an old app locked at v1.5.11 of Nokogiri and I couldnt get rid of this issue on Debian 9 until I upgraded Nokogiri to v1.6.8.1

Answer (score 0):

## Summary

`gem update --system & gem pristine nokogiri`
**`gem install nokogiri`**

(building up on [@Jonny answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33391982/272342) — **thank you** *!*)

## Details

I had the same error than in the title.
After running his command, running a ruby script failed with this error:

```
/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require': cannot load such file -- nokogiri (LoadError)
from /Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
from my_ruby_script.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

I then add to run `gem install nokogiri` again, and everything went back to normal.